# Vim assembly formatting

Tags: vim, indentation, assembly

Vim is not properly indenting assembly code, regardless of if I want it to do it automatically or if I try `gg=G` it'll just says *## lines indented* even though it didn't change anything and all my text is still left-aligned.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Vim does not do indenting of assembly out of the box. Looking in the /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent directory of Vim 7.4.335, there are no file names containing "asm" and neither `grep -i asm *` nor `grep -i assembl *` return any matches.

You could write your own indent plugin. See `:help indent-expression` for a start.

Comment: Writing my own plugin seems like a challenge, but it would give me some software credit and I could opensource it. This is the type of thing that can also go on a resume, right, if I wanted to?

**EDIT**
That was silly, putting something like that on a resume seems very stupid to me. In retrospect, I could publish it and that would...help the community, right? Could I then say I contribute to open-source software?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe vim didn't recognize filetype? Try

```
:set ft=nasm
```

and then run your indenting command.

or other options listed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782384/assembly-vim-syntax-highlighting

Comment: This changes the colors, but `gg=G` still doesn't work.

Comment: I did look at that thread though, and it wasn't very helpful. All I got out of it was a new colorscheme better than my custom one.

Answer (score 0):

I know this method isn't perfect, but it may be useful to you:

```
cp /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/python.vim ~/.vim/indent/nasm.vim
```

It will indent on a line after one that ends with `:`.

However, it won't unindent when you type a new label. Perhaps another syntax file would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

### vim-asm-indent

You might be interested [in a file](https://github.com/philj56/vim-asm-indent/blob/master/indent/asm.vim) that sets indentation after a label and unindents a label.